# How to prevent jsoup from retrying

Tags: java, jsoup

How do I effectively prevent jsoup from retrying to make a connection when the first try failed - for whatever reasons?

Which value for the timeout is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup wont retry to connect if the first attempt fails. It will throw a `ConnectException` instead. In general you can keep the default timeout value (3 seconds).

Btw. what method are you using? `parse()` or `connect()`? 2nd one is the better choice here.